# HTML/PHP/SQL Login Page Problems

Tags: php, mysql, html, authentication

having a bear of a time figuring out why my code isn't working. Basically, the username is **big** and the password is **foot**, after clicking submit, the database is queried and, once verified, page is redirected to my index.php. However, this is not happening. In fact, the submit button isn't even being detected by isset() when this username and password are entered. Yet, *if you enter ANY other username or password*, the isset() picks up on the form submission. Wierd? Solvable? You tell me! Here is my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once '../dbConn.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
        echo "submit button detected...<br />";
        echo '<script>alert("this is working...");</script>';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM flubberFitProfiles WHERE username=:username AND password=:password";
        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare ( $sql );
        $stmt->execute ( array (
                ":username" => $_POST ['name'],
                ":password" => hash ( "sha1", $_POST ['pass'] )
        ) );
        $record = $stmt->fetch ();
        echo "record has been fetched...<br />";
        }

        if (!empty($record)){
            $_SESSION ['username'] = $record ['username'];
            $_SESSION ['adminName'] = $record ['firstName'] . " " . $record ['lastName'];
            header ( "Location: index.php" );
        }
        else if (empty($record)){
            $errorArray = array (
                    "Wrong username/password"
            );
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META charset="utf-8">
        <TITLE>Please Log In</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>  
        <H1>Please log in to update your profile:</H1>
        <BR />
        <BR />
        <form method="post" action="login.php">
            Username: <INPUT type="text" id="name" name="name" required /><BR />
            Password: <INPUT type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required /><BR />
            <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <br />
        <!--
        To test the features, use:<br />
        username: big<br />
        password: foot<br />
        -->
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Do you have any custom error handling set up? The `header` call will issue a warning as you have already outputted stuff to the browser. What happens if you replace that with an `exit()` statement?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I ended up figuring it out! To answer you question: no, I don't have any custom error handling set up yet. I need to get on that so I can avoid these kinds of problems in the future. Thank you for you time as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...took me several hours, but it's always the simple things that trip me up! Turns out that I just forgot to include the `session_start()` command on the page that this one is redirecting to. Without that, my index.php page will never know if I successfully logged in or not and keep redirecting back to the login.php page. Works perfectly now!